# TypeError: can't pickle _tkinter.tkapp objects while using dill library

Tags: python, tkinter, compiler-errors, pickle, dill

So, i have class like this:

```
class Category:
def __init__(self,name):
    self.bt = Button(t, text = name, command = lambda : opencategory(name))
    self.packing()
def packing(self):
    self.bt.pack(fill = X)
def pack_forg(self):
    self.bt.pack_forget()
```

Then i create list of Category objects, for example like this:

```
list_cat = [Category("a"), Category("b"), Category("c")]
```

I use dill module to save this list into file:

```
   if list_cat != []:
        with open("file.pkl","wb") as f2:
            dill.dump(list_cat, f2)
```

But when I run it, it returns `TypeError: can't pickle _tkinter.tkapp`
I am open to any kind of solutions, using JSON, pickle, dill or anything else.

Here is an entire working code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os.path
from os import path
import dill

t = Tk()
t.title("test7")
t.geometry("100x300")
a = 1
list_cat = []

if path.exists("test777.pkl"):
    with open("test777.pkl","rb") as filee:
        list_cat = dill.load(filee)    

def opencategory(sampletext):
    print(sampletext)

class Category:  
    def __init__(self,sampletext):
        self.bt = Button(t, text = sampletext, command = lambda : opencategory(sampletext))
        self.packing()
    def packing(self):
        self.bt.pack(fill = X)
    def pack_forg(self):
        self.bt.pack_forget()


def save_c():
    if list_cat != []:
        with open("test777.pkl","wb") as file:
            dill.dump(list_cat, file)
def add_c():
    global a 
    list_cat.append(Category(a))
    a += 1


save = Button(t, text = "save", command = save_c)
save.pack(fill = X)
add = Button(t, text = "add", command = add_c)
add.pack(fill = X)


for i in list_cat:
    i.packing()
```

Comment: Isn't anything also named list_cat or f2? Also please post a full working code!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pickle a list of objects. Each of those objects contains a widget. You cannot pickle widgets. It simply cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the `dill` author. I agree with @Bryan_Oakley. But to be more clear, `_tkinter` is not python (I believe it's C++).  The issue is that any of the python serializers will not be able to pickle a non-python object, unless the python class that sits above it gives serialization directives (as a `numpy` array does).  `Tkinter` does not.

You can try different serialization variants in `dill` (in `dill.settings`), but likely it will fail.

You could, potentially, build a derived class of widget where you have added serialization directives that inform the serializer how to store the state of the widget. That should work -- and essentially, it's what can be done for any class object to become serializable.